# Animation Problem

Tags: animation

I made multiple animation actions for a character. In every action, I created keyframes only for the bones that are changing from the static pose and so there are no keyframes for the bones that aren't changing at all compared to the static pose.

The problem is when I run an animation (anim#1) that rotates a bone and if I play another animation (anim#2) that has no keyframe for that bone anim#2 will keep the rotation for the bone from anim#1 and not uses the rotation (and other transforms) from the static pose.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

The only thing I could think of is creating a single keyframe for each bone with all the transform at the beginning of each animation action.

Comment: I would say you need to create a keyframe for all your bones

Comment: you solution is the last sentence of your question...or write a python script which does this for you